# Removed XIB, the app crashes sometimes

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, ios-simulator

I'm facing a really annoying problem that I'm not able to solve.

I had a `.xib` with a couple of `IBOutlets` for one of my ViewControllers. I then removed the `.xib` and the `IBOutlets` choosing to take care of positioning the views myself.

Now the app crashes when it tries to load the ViewController with this error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<IntroViewController 0x20192480> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key logo.'
```

It makes me think that somewhere there's memory of the `.xib` and therefore it tries to load it. But I've deleted the `.xib` and also runned a `grep 'logo' ./*` to see if it's somewhere, but with no positive results. I've also checked for that file in the "Copy Bundle Resources" but of course it's not there.

I've noticed that if I remove the app from the simulator the problem disappears, but I'm not able to fix it in my iPod Touch, not even removing the app. The whole project is versioned with git.

Any ideas??

Comment: This error could be caused by having the wrong class of UIViewController, Changing to the correct class will sort the problem if it is

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but all the classes are fine. I made sure to check everything I could before posting :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing snapshots in Organizer for the project, clean, close xcode, simulator, and re-run.

Comment: Good catch! I forgot about the snapshots! Now it runs.

Comment: As a side note, I first did: delete snapshots > remove app from device > close and reopen Xcode > run and it didn't work. Then I did remove app from device > clean > close and reopen Xcode > build > run, and it finally loaded my ViewController. Thanks!